# Jquery Grid ( columns in column )

Tags: jquery, grid

What I want to do is this: I want to create a grid in jquery ( Kendo ui) with 5 solumns and I want to put in the last 2 columns I want to put 6 columns each. I dont know if someone can understand what I want to do so here is a picture of my idea

Comment: so where is the picture of your idea?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Here is my picture 

http://s11.postimage.org/gc4mqdusj/Untitled.png

Comment: Still nothing, I'm waiting for an answer to see if it is even possible to do such thing.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating columns in columns why not just create your 15 columns, 3 for the first 3 and 12 for the 6 in each of the last 2 columns.

Comment: That is basically what I want to do, the problem is that i don't know how to insert columns in columns. I don't know if the kendo grid allows to have columns inside the columns. If that is possible could You please tell me how to do it. I need this functionality in order to make hide and show on the columns on the right using the column menu.

Comment: That was not what I was suggesting, I was suggesting just using 15 columns, rather than 5 with 6 inside each of the last 2.  You could just hide columns 4 thourgh 9 and 10 through 15 respectivley when you click the column menus.

Comment: That is all fine, the problem is with the using of the column menu of the kendo grid (here's the example from kendo:http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/column-menu.html). As You can see, it gives only permission to hide and show the columns one by one, it is set by default like that. Do You know a way how to configure the menu? Let's say we want to hide 5 columns, is it possible to create some custom column menu that will hide them on click just like hiding only one column?